# Is this question asked in the right manner?

Tags: past-tense, present-tense

"Do you think the children enjoyed their meal?"

As you can see, this question started with the "Present Tense's auxiliary verb" which was "Do". Why can we still use Past Tense's verb (enjoyed) then?

By the way, I'm a newbie. Named "David"

Comment: I ***think*** your question ***was*** asked in the right manner.

Comment: You're currently thinking about enjoyment that may or may not have occurred in the past.

Comment: *Do you think this question **belonged** on 
[English Language Learners?*](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: FumbleFingers - Can I know what's the difference between learners and non- learners?

Comment: @EnglishGuy-David he just mentioned ell.stackexchange.com

Comment: @EnglishGuy-David - Some people just never learn.

Answer (score 2):

"Did you think that the children enjoyed their meal?"  This means - at the time the observer was present for the meal -  "Do ..." is a present tense question that asks the observer to look back in retrospect.

Answer (score 0):

> The question was asked correctly

"Did you think that the children enjoyed their meal?" 
The speaker strongly doubts whether the children enjoyed their meal.

Answer (score 0):

The question is correct. It means: do you think that yesterday's meal was appreciated by the children? The speaker asks a question now about an event that took place in the past.

Like: do you think yesterday's film was worth what we paid for the ticket? You talk about the film the day after you watched it.